# isAuthenticated not recognized on rewritten pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, url-rewriting

I'm using the UrlRewriting module on my site and I can't seem to get HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated to return "true" on any rewritten pages.

If I go to my home page (http://localhost/default.aspx) I get "true", but if I go to something like (http://localhost/contactus) I am always getting "false".

why would this be?

also, for a direct example, I have an edit bar that is supposed to appear to anyone who is authenticated.  The if statement fires in the Page_Load method

```
If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated Then _ 
Me.FindControl("EditBar").Visible = True
```

I have also tried putting this in the page load event

```
Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated.ToString)
```

Every page that is rewritten says "False" where pages that are not rewritten say "True".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, wherever the code in my question DIDN'T work, then this code did.

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025398/urlrewriting-net-module-iis7-equals-page-user-null). Does adding the following to your web.config fix your problem?

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Comment: unfortunately no, I've been running with that since the beginning.