# UrlRewriting.Net Module + IIS7 Equals Page.User == null?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-7, url-rewriting, forms-authentication

I've used the UrlRewriting.Net module for a couple years now without any problems in Windows XP and Windows 2003. I just recently upgraded my home PC to Windows 7 and started developing a new website.

The plan was to use .html extensions and rewrite them to their .aspx counterparts using the UrlRewriting.Net module. Everything **works flawlessly in VWD 2008**, but when I try running it through IIS7 it is a different story.

When I try to access a page via the .html rewrite I can no longer access Page.User; it keeps returning null.  If I hit the page using it's .aspx extension, Page.User is correctly populated. I should also mention that I have a LoginView controller in my Master Page and it suffers from the same symptoms: When accessing via .html extension it shows the AnonyousTemplate; When using .aspx extension it properly shows the LoggedInTemplate. I'm guessing the two are related.

[Note: I've also tried extensionless URLs and they exhibit the same problem]

The only way I've gotten it to work is to switch the application pool to Classic, which then requires me to add an ASP.Net ddl handler for the .html extension [otherwise it is handled by the StaticFileHandler and comes up as a 404 error].  However, I'd like my web app to run properly for people without having to fiddle around with IIS.

So I am left with several questions:

- Does anyone have ideas as to why Page.User always equals null for .html => .aspx rewritten pages?
- Why does it work in VWD 2008, but not IIS7?
- What changed from IIS6 => IIS7 that could have caused this?
- Any other thoughts on workarounds?

[Note: I just tried a .aspx => .aspx rewrite and it did not exhibit the problem. Not really what I want, but thought I should mention it.]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just had a breakthrough with the UrlRewriting.Net module.  This makes it work in Integrated Mode in IIS7:

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`

After figuring it out I did a search on "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" and the first thing that popped up was [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) which actually talks about using it for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah the Integrated mode within IIS is the primary difference between IIS6 & 7. You may want to look at Moving an ASP.NET application from IIS6 to IIS7 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515251.aspx).

As you've discovered, VWD 2008 runs everything through .NET, so it's effectively running in integrated mode with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true.

Comment: Thanks Sam. You are spot on. It does solve the problem. I would vote your answer but dont have enough reputations :(

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that seems to work is to remove the Session module and readd it leaving the "Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers" checkbox unchecked.  It looks like this in the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="Session" />
    <add name="SessionManualAdd" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

It seems the problem is that the Session module doesn't execute for say '*.htm' files when HttpContext.RewritePath is used, but removing and readding the module in this fashion causes the Session handler to be executed for the request.

This solution was suggested on the thread below.  Unfortunately Microsoft chose not to explain the reasoning behind this behavior fully:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357248/context-rewritepath-disables-session-module-in-iis7

Comment: Hi,

I had the method mentioned above "remove and then re-add session manually". I did work with my paging but later on when I was creating CMS it started creating problems with Session_Start event in Global.asax. This event was not firing at all. 

I then used the method above "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests", I am glad that I can see my pages back at least for now. Hope there will be no further issues.

So I would like to warn people who are planning to use the first technique.

Thanks for your post, you really solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft included a fix for this issue (at least for extensionless urls) in Service Pack 1 for Win7 and Windows Server 2008 R2:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5842

Also available as a hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

> After this patch is applied, ASP.NET 4 applications can handle requests for extensionless URLs. Therefore, managed HttpModules that run prior to handler execution will run. In some cases, the HttpModules can return errors for extensionless URLs. For example, an HttpModule that was written to expect only .aspx requests may now return errors when it tries to access the HttpContext.Session property.

After applying SP1 or the hotfix, no web.config changes are needed to make the session and forms auth work for extensionless URLs rewritten to asp.net pages/handlers/etc.

I don't know if this fixes anything for rewrites to static file extensions like .htm.  My guess is, probably not.  I would try to avoid setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in production environments, because it adds unnecessary overhead on static file requests.